# PHP showing stored checkbox data to an update form

Tags: php, mysql, database

I was wondering if anyone could help, I am creating an update product form which is showing results of data already in the database. I want to display all the checkbox categories and have the ones that have already been selected as checked so the user can easily select and change.

I know I am overcomplicating the code below but I am really no sure how to go about this. The code below currently selects all the categories and displays them as checkboxes but I cant get it to display the ones the user has already selected and saved to the db as checked. Also I am using MySQL original version not the improved one which I know I should be but If anyone could help I would really appreciate it Thanks Louise.

```
<?php

             $query  = "SELECT *  FROM category, catid_productid WHERE catid_productid.product_id ='$product_id' ORDER BY product_id ASC";
             $result = mysql_query($query);

             $query  = "SELECT *  FROM category, catid_productid WHERE category.cat_id = catid_productid.cat_id AND catid_productid.product_id ='$product_id' ORDER BY product_id ASC";
             $selected_result = mysql_query($query);
             $selected_array = array($selected_result);


             while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                {

                    $title= $row ['title'];
                    $cat_id= $row ['cat_id'];
                    echo '<li><label for="category-'.$cat_id.'" id="labelleft">'.$title.'</label>';
                    echo '<input name="category[]" id="category-'.$cat_id.'" type="checkbox" class="formbox" value="'.$cat_id;
                    if (isset($_GET['product_id']) && in_array($selected_array['$selected_result'], $selected_array)) {
                        echo 'checked="checked"';
                    }
                    echo " /></li>'";


                }
             ?>
```

form field:

```
<div class="field-row ">
     <label for="categories"> Categories:<?php
            if (isset($required) && in_array('category', $required)) { ?>
            <span class="warning">*</span><?php } ?></label>
            <div class="fields">
            <ul>

             <?php 
             $query  = "SELECT *  FROM category ORDER BY title ASC";
             $result = mysql_query($query);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                {
                    $title= $row ['title'];
                    $cat_id= $row ['cat_id'];
                    echo '<li><label for="category-'.$cat_id.'" id="labelleft">'.$title.'</label>';
                    echo '<input name="category[]" id="category-'.$cat_id.'" type="checkbox" class="formbox" value="'.$cat_id.'" /></li>';
                }
             ?>

            </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
```

inserting it into the database

```
if($result) {
            $product_id = mysql_insert_id();

            foreach ($category as $cat_id)
            {
            // connect to mysql database
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO catid_productid (cat_id, product_id) VALUES ('$cat_id', '$product_id')");
            }
```

Comment: How are you storing the checked-or-not information in the database?

Comment: As a boolean value either 0 for not selected and 1 for selected. There is a separate category table and product table which are joined by a many to many relationship table called catid_productid, does this help?

Comment: Yeah. it helps. Which of the tables has that information? or do both of them have?

Comment: oh no its not a boolean value sorry, if it is checked it adds the cat_id and product_id to the catid_productid table thus joining the product and category tables together. I added above the code for that part of the form if this helps?

Comment: How are you getting user preferences? I see no place where you get the prefs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you store checked-or-not information in your DB but I do spot mis-quotation here ..

Try changing this

```
echo '<input name="category[]" 
        id="category-'.$cat_id.'" 
        type="checkbox" class="formbox" value="'.$cat_id;
```

To

```
echo '<input name="category[]" 
       id="category-'.$cat_id.'" 
       type="checkbox" class="formbox" value="'.$cat_id.'"';
```

AND this

```
echo " /></li>'";
```

to

```
echo ' /></li>';
```